# PROC SQL subquery/correlated query

Tags: sql, sas, subquery, aggregate-functions, proc-sql

```
pro sql number;
   create table daily_total as
   select distinct trans_dt,
      sum((select (quantity * unit_price) 
           from transaction_detail 
           where subcat_num = 1111 and trans_dt = a.trans_dt))
   from transaction_detail as a
   where trans_dt between '2015-01-01' and '2015-01-02';
quit;
```

I understand I can achieve the samething with group by but I want to do this by subquery for the learning experierence.

I essentially want to select the two distinct dates and return the sum of each individual transaction for the subcategory on that particular day.

Thank you.

Comment: You still have to use the group by.  Also, you need to give computed columns an alias for the "Create Table". Preferable with typcast to explicitly set the datatypes.

Comment: You absolutely should add SAS as a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, aggregate functions like SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN (depending on the SQL engine) do not run on subqueries themselves.

Consider the following adjustment where SUM is used inside the subquery. Also, I assume you want the subquery's date range to correspond to the outer query's date and one day in future. Hence, I use SAS's [INTNX()](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) function.

```
pro sql;
  create table daily_total as

  select distinct a.trans_dt,
    (select sum(b.quantity * b.unit_price)
     from transaction_detail As b
     where b.subcat_num = 1111  
     and (b.trans_dt between a.trans_dt 
          and intnx('day', a.trans_dt, 1)) As transaction_sum
   from transaction_detail a;

quit;
```

Comment: I'm never going to take `group by` for granted again!

Comment: Haha...Indeed `group by` reads better. This could be a simple aggregate query grouped by trans_dt without the `distinct` clause and subquery.